# MySQL Query to find out Matching Records

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Below are the 2 tables:

```
Employee(id, name, salary, dept_id, supervisor_id)

Department(dept_id,name)
```

Write a query IN MySQL or Oracle:

1. Select all the names of supervisor whose age is greater than 60.
2. Select all the names of the department where at least 1 Employee is there.

Comment: Homeowork assignment ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see age column.(not enough information)
2. select distinct(name) from Department where dept_id in(select dept_id from Employee);

Comment: I Missed out DOB column in Employee Table. The Employee table actually looks like Employee(id, name, salary, dept_id, supervisor_id,date_of_birth).